# Given 2 unsorted arrays, A and B such that all elements of A belongs to B, how to find the smallest element of B that does not occur in A in O(n)?

Tags: algorithm

This is a coding interview question that I am not able to solve in O(n) time.
The size of B is twice the size of A. Also, the question states that no hashing is allowed. Is there any way to accomplish the task in O(n) time complexity?

Comment: Are the elements some arbitrary type that you can only do comparisons with, or can you do anything else (besides hashing)? Is it permitted to mutate either array?

Answer (score 2):

IF it is guaranteed that A and B contain no duplicates, then you can do this using a variant of [Quickselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) that operates on both arrays:

1. Choose a pivot from B and partition both A and B around the pivot
2. If A has fewer elements than B that are less than the pivot, then recurse on the partitions that are less than the pivot;
3. Otherwise, if the pivot does not occur in A, then that's your answer;
4. Otherwise, recurse on the partitions that are greater than the pivot.

The simple implementation of this takes *expected* O(n) time.  If you use [median-of-medians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians) to choose the pivot, then you can do it in O(n) worst case time.